# His Holiness Sri Ramanuja and anya dEvata worship

Tags: vaishnavism, ramanujacharya

Did His Holiness Sri Ramanuja say anya dEvata should not be worshipped? If yes, did His Holiness clarify the meaning of anya dEvata? Is it written down in any of the works of His Holiness?

Comment: Anyadevata means any Jiva who is a devata, like Shiva, Indra, etc. But you can worship Nityasuris like Adisesha, etc.

Comment: @Ikshvaku thanks for the comment. I understand many followers of His Holiness Sri Ramanuja believe / follow what you mentioned. However my question is a little different. It is about the basis for that belief system. Is it something that was handed down from generation to generation as a matter of faith, claiming to be the instruction of His Holiness Sri Ramanuja? or Is it something that can be traced to His Holiness Sri Ramanujacharyar's writings?

Comment: Like for example is it mentioned in His work like Vedartha Sangraha? If yes I would like to know how His Holiness argues for this assertion with evidence from The Vedic passages. So my interest is more in understanding what His Holiness actually said. If this was more of a faith followed through generations, attributed to His Holiness Sri Ramanuja, then that's a different matter.

Comment: To elaborate - one can quote Vedic passages to argue Lord Shiva is Paramatma. In the Vedas Indra enjoys an exalted position. So I am interested in reading the definition of anya dEvata, basis on which Sri Ramanuja explains it etc. As we know, His Holiness quotes from Upanisads in many of his works, like The Sri Bhashyam. So I assume if this notion came from Sri Ramanuja, one of his works may have additional notes, with support from Vedic passages. I am seeking that kind of reference. That said, Personally I am of the view Lord Shiva is Parabrahman, but that is a different matter.

Comment: Anyadevata Aradhana is only forbidden for people who have done Samashrayanam. They are prohibited from worshipping Shiva, Indra, Agni, Ganesha, Parvati, etc. They can only worship Narayana, his purusha avatars, his wives, and nityasuris.

Comment: "To elaborate - one can quote Vedic passages to argue Lord Shiva is Paramatma." | Not really according to Ramanujacharya. In his work called *Vedartha Sangraha*, he gives an argument to show that Narayana only is the Para Brahman. You can read it here starting from page 42: http://www.srimatham.com/uploads/5/5/4/9/5549439/vedartha_sangraha_.pdf

Comment: Thank you again @Ikshvaku. I am very well aware that Vaishnavas (I mean the followers of Sri Ramanujacharya) go by that notion (that Lord Shiva is a jivatma). I was interested in locating the literature where Sri Ramanuja provides His arguments. You answered it in your comment, thank you. I do have a copy of Vedartha Sangraha, I will go back and take a look. That said, I still want to know if His Holiness explicitly mentioned about the prohibition on worshiping other deities (anya devata) as you mentioned in the previous comment. Do you, by any chance, have references to that claim?

Comment: I am aware of some of the arguments His Holiness Sri Ramanujacharya puts forward in Brahma Sutra. But this perspective about anya dEvata, specifically offering instructions for worship, seems like an extended view of Sri Ramanuja from whatever I have seen. Though His Holiness might have been pronounced this explicitly somewhere, I am not sure if that's the case. So interested in understanding the origins of this notion / faith.

Comment: correction in the earlier message - drop that "been" (might have been => might have). I am unable to go back and edit that comment. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if Ramanujacharya has written not to worship anyadevatas anywhere in his works, but disciples later on like Nadadur Ammal have said so. Nadadur Ammal has said in his *Prapanna Parijata*, " Those who desire Liberation should not worship the other gods". | Please check Chapter 6 here: http://www.srimatham.com/uploads/5/5/4/9/5549439/prapanna_parijata.pdf

Comment: I see, thank you. So why don't you post this as an answer (instead of as a comment) so that I can accept it? Of course, if you care ..
I am not familiar with Nadadur Ammal's works... so will certainly check it out.
But what you are saying reinforces (if not confirms) my speculation that this notion about anya dEvata worship (and the associated restrictions) evolved in the post Desikan times.

Comment: I will post it as an answer soon, but this belief didn't evolve later but is based on mainly the pancharatra agamas and vishnu purana.

Comment: accepted the answer, and thanks again. I have read sections of The Vishnu Purana, which I consider to be more authentic than Srimad Bhagavatam, but I do not recall exact support for this restriction involving anya dEvata worship. If you can remember the chapters in The Vishnu Purana please let me know for my notes.

Comment: @vidyarthi Nadadur Ammal was born less than 30 years after Ramanuja passed away and nearly a century before Desika was born. Unless you dispute the authorship of the Prapanna Parijatham, explicit injunctions against anya devataa worship were in vogue long before Desika's time.

Comment: @hashable thanks for the comment. To your point, no I do not dispute the authorship of Prapanna Parijatham. I subscribe to a different philosophy of course, but I do not dispute the authorship of the texts referred in this Q&A. As for my background, I have more of Vedic roots with extremely selective consideration & application of The Puranas. Of course The Vedic passages are interpreted differently by different Acharyas and I respect all of them.  I am interested in understanding the wide ranging interpretations and the basis for them. That's the motivation behind my question. Contd below -

Comment: continuing - For the sake of completion, I do not accept the definition of mOksha or saranAgati or paramAtman exactly the way the followers of Sri Ramanuja's school do. But I do accept Sriman Narayana as The Paramatman though not with the sense of exclusivity (and sensitivity to the name and forms of deities) found in some of the Bhakti-Vedanta schools including, but not limited to, the schools of Sri Ramanuja. I separate metaphysics from theology, and with that separation, a different philosophical school is more appealing to me. 
But I respect all the schools, faith, and The Acharyas.

Comment: @hashable also when you find time, can you help me with some references to illustrate your last statement (quoting - "explicit injunctions against anya devataa worship were in vogue long before Desika's time"). Particularly are there references you know of, that highlight some of these injunctions *before* Nadadur Ammal's time, or before the time of Sri Ramanuja, or even Sri Yamunacharya? 
Any references you can offer will be helpful. The older the reference is, the better for my study. Thanks in advance for the references, and thanks for contributing to the discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did His Holiness Sri Ramanuja say anya dEvata should not be worshipped? If yes, did His Holiness clarify the meaning of anya dEvata? Is it written down in any of the works of His Holiness?

I'm not sure if Ramanujacharya said that anywhere, but later disciples like Nadadur Ammal definitely have.

Nadadur Ammal in *[Prapanna Parijata](http://www.srimatham.com/uploads/5/5/4/9/5549439/prapanna_parijata.pdf)* says in chapter 6:

> Those who desire Liberation should not worship the other gods

And this belief is not a later development but is based on the Pancharatra Agamas, and Nadadur Ammal cites this verse from one of the Agamas:

> **As the Lord said to the attentive Vishvakesena;**— “Those who have been
>   entrusted with some cosmic authority should not be worshipped by those desirous of
>   Liberation. I shall specifically mention those partial manifestations (pradurbhavan).
>   The four-faced Brahma was entrusted with the work of projecting the universe into
>   being (srishthi) and the great God Shankara with the work of withdrawal of the universe
>   (samhara). The function of Buddha was to delude and Vyasa was appointed to
>   compile the Vedas. Arjuna was the greatest of archers and Parasurama (Jamadagni) of
>   powerful beings. Agni is the foremost of the Vasus and Vittesha (Kubera) [of the Eight
>   directional lords].

This is from an Agama that was recited by Narayana to Vishvaksena, but I don't know the name of it.

Comment: This includes sage Vyasa who is authority of Vedas and purnanas quite surprising because vyasa is avatar of sriman Narayana..and also Parasurama, why we need not worship Buddha is because his main task is for delusion of bad souls..Apart from Buddha all are worshippable.. including buddha if our anusandhana is right

Comment: @PrasannaR what you are saying is the traditional / religious view (and I don't mean there is anything wrong with taking that view). There are scholars who attribute this to the conflict between Hinduism and Buddhism in historic times. Generally religious / traditional accounts conflict with historic & research based conclusions. Similar views about Buddha are present (directly and indirectly) in many Puranas including The Vishnu Purana, and likewise views about Lord Shiva.

Comment: While it is hard to be sure either way, which is partly a reason there are multiple views, personally I subscribe to the view that all these are due to schism between various sects and religions. I don't see this religiously. There are many common elements in the literature of Buddhism and Hinduism to make the matter complicated, and I guess that's something natural in the evolution of religions, especially the ones that evolved into some form of institutionalized religion.

Comment: @PrasannaR The reason sri vaishnavas don't worship Vyasa and Parashurama is because they are Jivatmas. They are considered avatars, but they are avesha avatars, or ordinary jivatmas empowered by Brahman.

Comment: 28th manvantra Vyasa is sakshath vishnu avatar he is not avesha.. according to srimad bhagavatham Parasurama is also not avesha avatara if you have reference proof contradicting this please share.not of any srivaishnave acharyas book but orginal puranas or text supporting your statements

Answer (score 3):

> Did His Holiness Sri Ramanuja say anya dEvata should not be
>   worshipped?

Not explicitly, at least not in the Vedartha Sangraha. It is more a logical conclusion derived from other premises.

If worshipping/meditating upon the Parabrahman (a concept accepted by all Vedantins) is the fundamental way a jIva can embark on the path towards mokSha, then **worshipping the non-Parabrahman** is at best inefficient and at worst detrimental to the cause of liberation.

Since all Vedantins are mumukShus by definition, Srivaishnavas/Visistadvaita-vedantins (who believe that Sriman Narayana is the Parabrahman) in their daily practices avoid the specific worship of anybody else (anya devatas). (There are nuances to this but this should suffice for the purpose of this question.)

The crux of the confusion results due to conflating terminology used in common parlance to refer to both Parabrahman and the non-Parabrahman. Ramanuja in the Vedarthasangraha is very clear in using the term *deva/sura* and it frequently in the compound *sura-nara-tiryak-sthAvara* or *deva-manuShya-tiryak-sthAvara*. If one stops using *deva/devatA* to refer to the Parabrahman, then there is no question of "anya-devatA". Every "deva/devatA" is "anya" from the Parabrahman (at least in the same way as your hand is not the same as you).

We can clearly find this information in the Vedartha Sangraha of Sri Ramanuja. It boils down the following concepts:

1. There are no separate categories called Gods (deva / sura). It is just one of the four categories of bodies (deva/heavenly, manuShya/human, tiryak/animal, sthAvara/plant) into which jIvas enter on account of accumulated beginingless karma.
2. Starting from the four-faced creator Brahma and descending, everybody is a jIva and are subject to karma (unlike the Parabrahman who is not subject to karma)
3. Meditation/Worship of the Parabrahman is the means to attain Him.

**Some quotes from the Vedarthasangraha:**

> asya jīvātmano
>   anādy-avidyā-saṃcita-puṇya-pāpa-rūpa-karma-pravāha-hetuka-**brahmādi-sura-nara-tiryak-sthāvar**ātmaka-caturvidha-deha-praveśa-kṛta...

The jIva has accumulated puNya and pApa karma on account of beginningless avidyA. This results in its entry into four kinds of bodies - sura, nara, tiryak, sthAvara. This applies to all jIvas starting from Brahma and descending.

> atredaṃ sarvaśāstrahṛdayam ... tattatkarmānurūpajñānasaṃkocam āpannāḥ,
>   brahmādistambaparyantavividhavicitradeheṣu praviśṭās ...tadupāsana
>   sāṅgaṃ tatprāpakaṃ pratipadayanti śāstrāṇīti /

The following is the essence of all Sastras: ... The consequence is that the scope and breadth of their (jIvas) knowledge is curtailed in accordance with their karma. They (jIvas) get embodied in the multifarious varieties of bodies from Brahma down to the lowest species such as a tuft of grass or a stone pillar.... They (Sastras) teach meditation along with its accessory conditions as the means for attaining the Parabrahman.

There are many more such quotes in the Vedarthasangraha including references to Sruti/Smriti/Purana.

---

The explicit injunction to not worship "anya devatas" by mumukShus is a clarification provided by post Ramanujan acharyas as mentioned by Ikshvaku.

In recognition of the fact that several daily and occasional obligations include the propitiation of devatas, Srivaishnavas include 'bhagavat prItyartham' or 'bhagavat kainkarya rUpam' in the sankalpas of all vedic karmas.

Comment: Is it true that anya-devata worship immediately cancels/or can cancel sharanagati?

Comment: This is a point of controversy depending on who you speak to. I am not very familiar with the Thengalai position on this. But the Vadagalai position is mokSha can be delayed if there are any flaws in the execution of sharanagathi. Desika is very clear about this. The controversy is on the extent of the delay (whether or not it can delay to another birth).

Comment: So if it didn't delay to the next life, then it means one's current life would just be longer?

Comment: What about this case? Suppose someone does bharanyasam with full conviction Narayana will grant moksha, and then later in life he worships some anyadevata for a phala. Would that delay moksha?

Comment: I just saw that you updated your post with this line: "In recognition of the fact that several daily and occasional obligations include the propitiation of devatas". But my understanding is that the devatas are not being propitiated in nitya karmas, but only the *antaryami* of devatas (Narayana) is being propitiated, or should be propitiated.

Comment: I'm not sure StackOverflow is the right forum to discuss nuances of Sharanagati. Happy to have a private conversation.    Regarding your other question, one does propitiate other devatas; however, there is the recognition that the ultimate cause is the antaryami who acts through these devatas. E.g. the rules for reciting mantras for Brahma are to recite them silently. When an act towards Rudra is done in the middle of some karma, water is touched to purify the hand (apa upasprishya). These would be unnecessary if these devatas are not being invoked/addressed.

Comment: That would be great. You can add me on hangouts. Prithvi.Mandayam@gmail.com. Adiyen Dasan.

Comment: @hashable thank you for the clear response. A couple of points I like to add as a qualifiers for others who may stumble upon this Q&A (meaning, no need to dispute or converge on the following)
(1) The notion of Paramatman differs across the school, and I understand Sri Ramanuja school takes Lord Sriman Narayana exclusively as Paramatman
(2) Your reference to Moksha deserves a comment - the definition of Moksha is described differently in scriptures (a separate topic), and also across the schools of philosophy
(3) You mentioned some nuances. Can you comment a little more on what those are?

Comment: @Vidyarthi Regarding your clarification on Moksha, I agree that the definition of Moksha may be different. However are you in agreement with my statement on Moksha (That parabrahma-upAsana is the way to mokSha) is universally applicable to all Vedantins? The statement itself is agnostic to the definition of Parabrahman and Moksha. The keyword in focus is upAsanA (which is basically same as the word "worship" in your question).

Comment: @Vidyarthi, I mentioned 'nuances' because Srivaishnavas do not exclusively worship Sriman Narayana. They also worship azhwars, acharyas and bhAgavathas. Ramanuja himself has declared in his last instruction that if one is unable to do any of the previous instructions, they should seek a Srivaishnava and live the rest of their life in their company serving them. I didn't mention it in detail because while it is possible to debate it similar to the case of anya-devata worship, it will require going into deeper waters of Srivaishnava philosophy/theology which I felt is not necessary here.

Comment: @hashable Thanks for staying on the topic and driving convergence (hard to see that these days). To your question, yes I agree that (quoting your statement) _"parabrahma-upAsana is the way to mokSha"_ . If that's the context in which anya dEvatA worship is not recommended in Sri Ramanuja's school of theology, you fully answered my question. Thank you. 
One thing I would like to add is - the notion & definition of upAsana varies across the sects, so I agree that "connecting" with parabrahman (one way or the other) seems to be the path to mOkShA across the schools.

Comment: @hashable thanks for the comment on the nuances. So as per Sri Ramanuja's school, what about those who worship Azwars and nithyasuris, acharyas? Are they considered to be on the path to mOkSha as defined by Sri Ramanuja's school?

Comment: @Vidyarthi My impression is that the definition of upAsanA is largely consistent across different Vedantic schools. Even more so is the treatment of other terms like 'vedana' which are consistently interpreted to be the same as 'upAsanA' e.g. in the sentence 'brahmavid Apnoti param'. The differences are more about the nature of mokSha and the definition of parabrahman, rather than in the definition of upAsanA. Otherwise mere "connecting with Parabrahman" framing would apply to any religion.

Comment: @Vidyarthi Azhwar and Acharyas are considered Avataras. There are differences of opinion on further subtle issues but nevertheless, their worship is compatible with the path to Moksha. Also achArya upAsana can be a proxy for brahma upAsana for those incapable of brahma upAsanA.  In fact, sharaNAgati itself is something like this (the brahma-upAsana experience is given by the Parabrahman to the jIva at final moment).  Again all these issues have nuances and the details have been a topic of debate in recent centuries.

Comment: @Vidyarthi On the topic of nityasuris, I myself have a lot of questions. I'd still like to make some points: (1) Nityasuri worship is not in isolation but always enjoined with Parabrahma worship. E.g. The garland offered to Garuda is first supposed to be offered to the Lord. As everywhere, the practice of these customs may not conform to theory, but the theory is present. (2) Largely there are only 2 Nityasuris that are worshipped - Garuda, and Vishvaksena and both have served the role of Acharyas in the Guru Parampara. (3) There are no temples exclusive to the Nityasuris to my knowledge.

Comment: @hashable I thank you for all your comments, answers, and the references. By the way Garuda incarnated as an acharya in the Sri Vaishnavism? Who was that Acharya? Vishvaksena is considered to have incarnated as Sri Nammazhar in Sri Vaishnavist school right? Or was it Sri Ramanuja? What about Sri Adisesha?

Comment: My reference to Garuda is to his transmission of the Hayagriva mantra to Vedanta Desika as recorded in the biographies of the Acharya. Vishvaksena is the direct acharya of Nammazhvar. Ramanuja is considered Adisesha's avatara.